# Limit number of characters in the stored field

Tags: java, solr, indexing, lucene

I have a document with 195 million characters. It gets indexed ok, but when it comes to displaying it to the user, I dont need to display it fully, just lets say 1 million characters or so, not to mention that Solr crashes as well.

Is it possible to limit number of characters stored/displayed, but index all. Like in copy field:

```
<copyField source="cat" dest="text" maxChars="30000" />
```

Comment: Maybe you want to use a `substring` function??

Comment: can u be a bit more specific pls? substring, when I get a result? It is pointless, as Solr breaks on 194 million characters anyways and even if not I have to transfer it over the network

Comment: @JordiCastilla, you do understand we are talking about Solr?

Comment: as I understand you problem is that your docs are very big and you want to limit storing but index it fully, right?

Comment: You could put two fields in your schema. The first for the complete doc with stored=false and indexed=true. The second would be stored=true and indexed=false from a corresponding copyField entry with maxChars=...

Comment: @Holger You should post that as an answer, as it's probably the best way of implementing it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly providing your own answer.

1. Use copyField with maxChars settings
2. Have the original field as stored=false, indexed=true
3. Have the copied field as stored=true, indexed=false
4. Search the original field, but return copied field

However, you may consider not having that content in Solr at all, but have it outside of Solr. At least if you have multiple documents like that in Solr.

Comment: what about highlighting?

Comment: With at least one of the highlighters, you tell which fields to highlight. Actually it is *more* work to highlight specifically the fields that matched for keywords that matched. So, it may work to your favor.

Comment: hi, i noticed that if the field is not indexed then you can't use termsvector = true. wouldn't that have an impact on highlighting performance?